# React router v6 pass an object to the URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Is it possible to pass an object to the URL?

Example:

```
item.idData = {carType: 2, carBrand: 3, carModel: null, carFuel: 3, carStates: null, …}

to={`/?${[item.idData]}`}
```

Result: `/?[object%20Object]`

Need result: `/?carType=2&carBrand=3&carModel=null&...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams):

```
item.idData = {carType: 2, carBrand: 3, carModel: null, carFuel: 3, carStates: null, …}
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(item.idData);
to={`/?${searchParams.toString()}`}
```